# Records in a guard

Tags: erlang

I'm attempting to use a record in a guard as described here[1].  If I use the short form described there:

```
handle(Msg, State) when Msg==#msg{to=void, no=3} ->
```

... I never get a match... however, if I fully expand it to:

```
handle(Msg, State) when Msg#msg.to==void, Msg#msg.no==3 ->
```

... all is well.  As it seems I do with most erlang docs, am I reading it wrong?

Thanks,
--tim

[1] - http://www1.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html#id2278275

Comment: just a guess but your first match assumes that there are no other fields in the record or that all other fields are set to undefined.

If the msg record has other fields that would cause it to fail.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that must be it (there are other valued fields), I thought they were semantically equivalent.  Thanks again...

Comment: Just as a further note you could have done this with pattern matching  in the function signature instead. The match failed because it did an equality test. You may have been tripped up by the visual similarity of == for equality and = for binding in a pattern match.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say `#msg{to=void, no=3}` in a guard, all the fields that you haven't mentioned will be set to their default (usually `undefined`). So your guard is failing to match because some of the fields not listed don't match.

I tend to always use a pattern rather than a guard where possible, so I would write the clause as:

```
handle(Msg = #msg{to=void, no=3}, State) ->
    ...
```

This pattern requires Msg to msg record (a tuple the size of an msg record with the first element being `msg`), the `to` element must be `void` and the `no` element must be 3. The other elements of the msg record can be anything.

Comment: Thanks everyone, as all have surmised, I should be using a pattern instead... this learning curve is steep but enjoyable... thanks again...

Answer (score 4):

I see you solved the problem already.  Just a note: in idiomatic Erlang you'd usually write the match like this:

```
handle(Msg = #msg{to = void, no = 3}, State) ->
```

Of course, it comes down to taste, and at times you'll want to use guards instead to get more pleasing line alignment.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use the following pattern instead, its succinct

```
handle(#msg{to=void, no=3}=Msg, State) ->
    do_stuff(Msg).
```

If you don't need the whole msg record value, but only some field within it then you can match and destruct like this

```
handle(#msg{to=void, no=3, data=Data}, State) ->
    do_stuff(Data).
```

Answer (score 0):

Matching records can be a hassle when they are large.  The way I deal with it is by testing the first element of the record, which should be the record name:

handle(Whatever) when element(1,Msg) == msg